# on click partial refresh javascript multiple inputs autocomplete function fails to bind

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, function, autocomplete

This question has been asked before in numerous ways and I have looked at many examples and tried many options but it is still not working.
Form page - button clicked to update a dropdown - partial refresh of the dropdown only.
Separate multiple input fields have a  javascript autocomplete function.
The autocomplete is working on page loads.
On clicking the button the javascript autocomplete function loses its binding to the page and does not work.
The function is losing the binding on partial page refresh

I've tried `$(document).ready(function()` (commented out in the code snip) but the browser throws a `$` is not a function' for the  `$(document).ready(function()`

How do I implement the bind so the autocomplete function works continuously?

```
cart loop {
<!--qty section-->

<td class="product-quantity" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
<?php
if ( $_product->is_sold_individually() ) {
    $product_quantity = sprintf( '1 <input type="hidden" name="cart[%s][qty]" value="1" />', $cart_item_key );

} else {
    $product_quantity = woocommerce_quantity_input(
        array(
            'input_name'   => "cart[{$cart_item_key}][qty]",
            'input_value'  => $cart_item['quantity'],
            'max_value'    => $mx_qty,
            'min_value'    => '1',
            'product_name' => $_product->get_name(),
        ),
        $_product,
        false
    );

echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_quantity', $product_quantity, $cart_item_key, $cart_item ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.
        
<td>
<table >
    <tbody class="autocomplete">
     <?php
     //On quantity refresh display corresponding number of inputs
     ($i=0; $i< $cart_item['quantity']; $i++){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td>    
            <input id="myInput<?php echo $i.$cart_item_key;?>" class='autoc' value="<?php echo $cart_item['woo_number'][$i];?>" name="woo_number<?php echo $cart_item_key;?>[]" type="text" autocomplete="off" pattern="[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" minlength="1" maxlength="4" min="1" style="font-family: inherit; line-height: 1; border-radius: 2px; border-style: solid; border-width:1px; border-color: #818181; padding: 2px;width: 100px !important;" border='1' data-product="<?php echo $product_id; ?>" required>
        </td>
    </tr>       
</tbody>
</table>
</td>

function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
    /*the autocomplete function takes two arguments,
    the text field element and an array of possible autocompleted values:*/
    var currentFocus;
    /*execute a function when someone writes in the text field:*/
    inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
        var a, b, i, val = this.value;
        var el_counter = 0;
        var el_len = 0;
        /*close any already open lists of autocompleted values*/
        closeAllLists();
        if (!val) {
            return false;
        }
        currentFocus = -1;
        /*create a DIV element that will contain the items (values):*/
        a = document.createElement("DIV");
        a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
        a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
        /*append the DIV element as a child of the autocomplete container:*/
        this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
        /*for each item in the array...*/
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            /*check if the item starts with the same letters as the text field value:*/
            if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length) == val) {
                el_counter++;
                el_len = el_len + arr[i].length;
                if (el_counter < 7 && el_len < 17) {
                    /*create a DIV element for each matching element:*/
                    b = document.createElement("DIV");
                    /*make the matching letters bold:*/
                    b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
                    b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
                    /*insert a input field that will hold the current array item's value:*/
                    b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";

                    /*execute a function when someone clicks on the item value (DIV element):*/
                    b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                        /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
                        inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
                        /*close the list of autocompleted values,
                        (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
                        closeAllLists();
                    });
                    a.appendChild(b);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    /*execute a function presses a key on the keyboard:*/
    inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
        var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
        if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
        if (e.keyCode == 40) {
            /*If the arrow DOWN key is pressed,
            increase the currentFocus variable:*/
            currentFocus++;
            /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
            addActive(x);
        } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
            /*If the arrow UP key is pressed,
            decrease the currentFocus variable:*/
            currentFocus--;
            /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
            addActive(x);
        } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            /*If the ENTER key is pressed, prevent the form from being submitted,*/
            e.preventDefault();
            if (currentFocus > -1) {
                /*and simulate a click on the "active" item:*/
                if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
            }
        }
    });

    function addActive(x) {
        /*a function to classify an item as "active":*/
        if (!x) return false;
        /*start by removing the "active" class on all items:*/
        removeActive(x);
        if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
        if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
        /*add class "autocomplete-active":*/
        x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
    }

    function removeActive(x) {
        /*a function to remove the "active" class from all autocomplete items:*/
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
        }
    }

    function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
        /*close all autocomplete lists in the document,
        except the one passed as an argument:*/
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
                x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    /*execute a function when someone clicks in the document:*/
    document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        closeAllLists(e.target);
    });
}

// $(document).ready(function() {    
// $('.woocommerce').on('change', '.autoc', function(){

/*An array containing all the available ltd ed nos*/
var arrlist = '';
arrlist = [ < ? php $avail_nos = get_post_meta($product_id, '_avail_nos', true);
    $comma_separated = implode("','", $avail_nos);
    $comma_separated = "'".$comma_separated.
    "'";
    echo $comma_separated ? >
];

var jsqty = 0;
var jskey = '';

jsqty = "<?php echo $cart_item['quantity'] ?>";
jskey = "<?php echo $cart_item_key ?>";

var str1 = '';
str1 = 'myInput';
/*initiate the autocomplete function on the "myInput" element, and pass along the countries array as possible autocomplete values:*/
for (var i = 0; i < jsqty; i++) {
    var num = i;
    var str2 = num.toString();
    var str3 = str1.concat(str2);
    var myInput = str3.concat(jskey);
    autocomplete(document.getElementById(myInput), arrlist);
}

//});
//});

} //end cart loop
```

[inital page load hint below the input box works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4w7Y.png)

[After update cart clicked hint below the input box does not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfROU.png)

[page reload hint below both input boxes works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVbqB.png)

Comment: Post the generated HTML and make it run.  I think you want to use $.on()

Comment: Yes I tried using on but it kills the JS completely. $(document).ready(function() {    
 $('.woocommerce').on('change', '.autoc', function(){

var arrlist = '';
arrlist =.....